# How to recursively mount file shares?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I have a Linux machine that shares some files through NFS. The shared directory is:

```
/foo
```

I then mounted a shared directory (from a Windows machine) to:

```
/foo/bar
```

/foo/bar is mounted successfully onto the Linux machine and everything is there. However any other machine that mounts /foo from the Linux machine everything is correctly there except /foo/bar is empty.

Is there anyway to do a "recursive mount" of file shares.

Here is the /etc/fstab entry for the Windows share mount of /foo/bar

```
//windows_machine/share /foo/bar cifs username=user,password=pass 0 0
```

And the /etc/fstab entry on the client machines that mount /foo

```
server:/foo /foo nfs rw 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `nohide` export option.